# Is it possible to connect Dialogflow (Api.ai) with Slack so that humans can monitor and possibly even intervene or add to the conversation via Slack?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I know Dialogflow (Api.ai) can be a bot in Slack.  But what about monitoring the conversation and possibly manually intervene in the conversation?  If possible, what would be the general direction to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

So `Slack` has Open APIs for interacting with the Slack App. [Here](https://api.slack.com/)

Since you want to monitor the conversations so Events APIs and Conversations APIs would help you to notify as well as capture the conversations.

[image: conversations.history]
`conversations.history` will help you to fetch the messages within public or private channels.

Since you want to intervene in the conversation then I suggest using chatbot, which will provide a suitable way to intervene and respond to some particular events. [Bot Users](https://api.slack.com/bot-users)

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow has an sample on how to do this: https://github.com/dialogflow/agent-human-handoff-nodejs

You'll have to build you own front end for the human to override the response and call the Dialogflow query API to integrate:

Slack <--> Front end w/human override <--> Dialogflow's query API <--> Dialogflow Agent

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just login to DialogFlow with your Google credentials, then on the left sidebar you can see the Integrations Tab. Click on it. You will find a bunch of different integrations for line, telegram, Twilio, kik, Viber, Skype and a lot more.

Click on Slack. It will ask you for some details for connecting with endpoints such as client ID, token, client secret. You can get it from the Slack API. You can also check the Slack API integration link [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth). After everything is properly set up, click the "Test in Slack" button in the DialogFlow Slack integration.